# using openpyxl Tokenizer to parse Excel IF statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel-formula, tokenize, openpyxl

I found [this doc on Tokenizer](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html?highlight=Tokenizer), but it doesn't say how to use the formula and actually execute it (seems pretty useless without that).

I have some simple `IF` cases I need to handle:

```
formula = '''IF(size<80000,size/80000*(1.85-1.65)+1.65,IF(size<160000
    (size-80000)/80000*(1.65-1.45)+1.45,IF(size<280000,(size-160000)/
    120000*(1.45-1.05)+1.05,IF(size<800000,(size-280000)/520000*(1.05-0.7)+0.7,0))))'''

from openpyxl.formula import Tokenizer
tok = Tokenizer(formula)
```

I can see the methods for `tok`:

```
print([d for d in dir(tok) if '__' not in d])
['ERROR_CODES', 'SN_RE', 'STRING_REGEXES', 'TOKEN_ENDERS', 'WSPACE_RE', '_parse', '_parse_brackets', '_parse_closer', '_parse_error', '_parse_opener', '_parse_operator', '_parse_separator', '_parse_string', '_parse_whitespace', 'assert_empty_token', 'check_scientific_notation', 'formula', 'items', 'offset', 'render', 'save_token', 'token', 'token_stack']
```

If I wanted to pass in `size=100` to this `tok` instance and execute it to get a returned result, how do I do that?

There is the obvious way of building an AST with the parsed tokens, but I'm curious if it is possible to write the formula to a an Excel doc in memory and execute the function that way, if that is easier. I do not have an Excel doc for this. I just have lots of formula strings.

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl never evaluates formulae. The tokenizer is solely used for unpacking and reassigning shared formulae. Other libraries do exist for evaluating formulae but you are generally better off passing the file to an application such as MS Excel or OpenOffice or LibreOffice for evaluation as these contain optimisations for the calculation, including parallelisation.

Comment: Do you know of any libraries that evaluate formulae? I'd like to try comparing the performance.

Comment: I think PyCell is the Python one but I've never used it.